# Lightweight Tree Implementation for Html

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a *lightweight* Tree-Implementation for Html(5) and JS that supports at least:

- Custom rendering of "nodes"
- Drag'n'Drop of nodes

The idea of being lightweight is that, besides jQuery, there should be no other dependencies for the tree, including but not limited to have no dependencies on jquery-ui at all.

I wasn't able to find any else than either jquery-ui based or commercial or huge codebase or without the given requirements.

thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718721/jquery-tree-with-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin is a great and very recommended JS library for implementing trees in HTML pages.

It supports JSON data, drag-n-drop and much more related features...

Take a look at its demo page: http://www.jstree.com/demo

As for HTML 5 support, take a look at this ticket: [Feature-Request: HTML5 attributes for metadata](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/170)